# driver.close() will hang for forever

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

driver.close() is not working on Jenkins and the whole test will hang for forever. I am using Selenium Grid with Java and using Chrome Driver.

I don't want to user `driver.quit()`. I have to use `driver.close()`. I have two tabs open and i have to close one.

```
public static void closeBrowser() 
{ 
    try 
    { 
       WebDriver testDriver = BrowserFactory.getInstance().getDriver(); 
        if (testDriver != null) 
        { 
            testDriver.close();
        } 
        wait.wait(2); 
        Log.info("Closing the browser"); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    { 
        Log.info("Cannot close browser"); 
    } 
}
```

This used to work and started to happen recently.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and trace level logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better solution i found to close window is:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) BrowserFactory.getInstance().getDriver()).executeScript( "window.close()" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this following:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "w");
```

This code will close the currently opened tab.

Comment: Well driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "w");
 solved my problem for now. driver.close() still does not work on Jenkins.